# Return an event.object to another function during collision - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my collision, I am detecting which spawns collide with my castle object at the bottom of the screen using event.object1.name and event.object2.name. this works fine but I would like to return that specific spawn (that collided with that castle) and use its event.object within another function if possible. How can I do this?

Cheers

My collision is as follows:

```
local function onCollision(event)
if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then

if event.object1 ~= nil and event.object1.name == "Blue" and event.object2 ~= nil and event.object2.name == "arrow" or event.object1 ~= nil and event.object1.name == "arrow" and event.object2 ~= nil and event.object2.name == "Blue" then 
    if event.object2.name == "arrow" then display.remove(event.object2) event.object2 = nil; onHit()


    elseif event.object1.name == "arrow" then display.remove(event.object1) event.object1 = nil; onHit()

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use the object befor you delete it.

`display.remove(event.object1)` removes object1 from the display.
`event.object.1 = nil` deletes it

```
function doSomethingWithTheObject(obj)
  -- do something fancy here
  print(obj.name)
end
```

Then befor you delete the object call your function:

```
doSomethingWithTheObject(event.object1)
```

Comment: Ah I see now, I was trying to pass event and return true at the end of my function so that I could access that event again in the other function. I see now that it was well wrong. Thanks for the super quick help, it works perfect now.